# How to play a video on a TV model inside a game?

Tags: c#, unity, javascript, unityscript

I am new to Unity3D. I need to know how can I play news when I switch on a TV using any scripting language in Unity3D ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to play a video in game? You should try to make your questions generic and clarify as much as possible when asking a question. Include what you've tried already and what about it didn't work.

Comment: Watch an online tutorial like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUq2fsL-gRs) for animated textures.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play a video on the TV screen, you would use [Movie Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html) (just have it render on a game object that you set active to true or false whenever a button is pressed. Keep in mind that Movie Texture is a Pro Only feature.

If you want to simply animate a set of sprites, the [Animated Texture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUq2fsL-gRs) solution [Arthur Wulf White](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71671/how-to-play-a-video-on-a-tv-model-inside-a-game#comment129593_71671) proposed is the way to go.

Comment: Be aware though that Movie Texture doesn't really work on mobile (it's mentioned in that link). That's why I've started experimenting with assets like EasyMovieTexture https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032